# what is storage virtualization in contrast to?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, storage

i'm reading up on storage virtualization

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_virtualization

and i'm trying to understand what this is in contrast to, or a solution to, or why it exists at all?

some guy came up with the idea of storage virtualization, why? why did he do it? what was the problem he was trying to solve? what was the other thing that wasn't good enough so he made storage virtualization?

what came before storage virtualization? why did storage virtualization come about? what problem did it solve?

thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about UNIX/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contrast to a physical disk that you use "as is" without any level of abstraction.

In the essence, this approach is used when you have multiple disks that you would like to manage as a single virtual entity.

Let's say you have 2 physical disks, each one has a capacity of 100GB. Without the idea of "storage virtualization", the maximum partition size you can create is 100GB (as the size of each drive). But you could combine those disks to one [logical disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disk) which would:

> provide an area of usable storage capacity on one or more physical
> disk drive(s) in a computer system. **The disk is described as
> *logical* or *virtual* because it does not actually exist as a single physical entity in its own right**. The goal of the logical disk is to
> provide computer software with what seems a contiguous storage area,
> sparing them the burden of dealing with the intricacies of storing
> files on multiple physical units.

Thus, using this approach, you'll have one virtual entity with a total 200GB capacity. Moreover, it provides you the flexibility of adding additional physical storage devices to this virtual drive that would increase it's capacity and extend it's size. In some implementations you could even replace a disk. So this is a level of abstraction that provides greater flexibility for managing physical storage.

There are many different implementation approaches for this concept, described in the wiki page in your question, such as [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_virtualization#Host-based), [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_virtualization#Storage_device-based) and [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_virtualization#Network-based).